# Forcing the optimizer to execute view independently

Tags: sql, view, oracle11g, query-optimization, hint

Simple tables: Department and Employee, one to many etc

Complex view: Employee_contract_properties (EMPL_ID, PROPERTY_NAME, PROPERTY_VALUE) 200 row of code, 3 000 000 rows of data etc

Performed instantly.

```
SELECT e.id
FROM department d INNER JOIN employee e ON e.dept_id = d.id AND a.job = 'DBA'
WHERE d.name = 'IT'
```

Result: 
5,7,13,etc

Performed instantly.

```
SELECT p.property_value
FROM employee_contract_properties p
WHERE p.empl_id IN (
    5, 7, 13, etc
)
AND p.property_name = 'empl_cat_name';
```

But this is executed for 5 minutes long because Oracle mess with query execution order.

```
SELECT p.property_value
FROM employee_contract_properties p
WHERE p.empl_id IN (
    SELECT e.id
    FROM department d INNER JOIN employee e ON e.dept_id = d.id AND a.job = 'DBA'
    WHERE d.name = 'IT'
)
AND p.property_name = 'empl_cat_name';
```

I need something like that but failed to find a suitable hint. Is there such a thing?

```
SELECT p.property_value
FROM employee_contract_properties p
WHERE /*+ RESPECT_MY_AUTHORITAH */ p.empl_id IN (
    SELECT e.id
    FROM department d INNER JOIN employee e ON e.dept_id = d.id AND a.job = 'DBA'
    WHERE d.name = 'IT'
)
AND p.property_name = 'empl_cat_name';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ROWNUM`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255) is a quick, easy way to prevent the Oracle optimizer from combining query blocks.  Due to the way `ROWNUM` is used for Top-N reporting it is applied late in the execution plan, which helps disable optimizer transformations for a specific query block.

There are hints to accomplish the same goal, perhaps `SELECT /*+ NO_UNNEST */ ...`.  Hints can be very tricky to get right, adding a `ROWNUM` is usually easier:

```
SELECT p.property_value
FROM employee_contract_properties p
WHERE p.empl_id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM
  (
    SELECT e.id, rownum /* rownum added for performance */
    FROM department d INNER JOIN employee e ON e.dept_id = d.id AND a.job = 'DBA'
    WHERE d.name = 'IT'
  )
)
AND p.property_name = 'empl_cat_name';
```

The code below demonstrates how `ROWNUM` can be used to stop optimizer transformations.

**Sample schema and data**

```
--drop table employee;
--drop table department;

create table department(dept_id number primary key, name varchar2(100));
create table employee(id number primary key, name varchar2(100), dept_id number,
    constraint employee_if foreign key (dept_id) references department(dept_id));

insert into department select level, level
  from dual connect by level <= 100;
insert into employee select level, level, mod(level, 100)+1
  from dual connect by level <= 100000;

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'department');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'employee');
end;
/
```

**Query that benefits from transformation**

Below is a very backwards way of writing "give me employee 1 who belongs to department '2'.".  Instead of putting `employee.id = 1` in the outer query block, next to the EMPLOYEE table, it is awkwardly put in the subquery.  This demonstrates how optimizer transformations can often save you from yourself.

```
explain plan for
select *
from employee
where dept_id in
(
    select dept_id
    from department
    where department.dept_id = employee.dept_id
        and employee.id = 1 --primary key predicate
        and department.name = '2'
);
```

The optimizer is smart enough to re-write the above query as a simple join and it applies the primary key predicate first.

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => '-bytes'));

Plan hash value: 4183381282

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name         | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |              |     1 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |              |     1 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EMPLOYEE     |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0013597 |     1 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| DEPARTMENT   |     1 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0013596 |     1 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("EMPLOYEE"."ID"=1)
   4 - filter("DEPARTMENT"."NAME"='2')
   5 - access("DEPT_ID"="DEPT_ID")
```

**Preventing the transformation**

Add a `ROWNUM`, which also requires adding another inline view because the `in` only expects one value.  Be sure to add a comment to explain what the seemingly unnecessary column is used for.

```
explain plan for
select *
from employee
where dept_id in
(
    select dept_id
    from
    (
        select dept_id, rownum /* rownum added for performance */
        from department
        where department.dept_id = employee.dept_id
            and employee.id = 1
            and department.name = '2'
    )
);
```

Now that the subquery unnesting is prevented the execution plan must loop through every row in EMPLOYEE and apply the subquery to it.  In this case the new plan is much more expensive but it demonstrates the concept.

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => '-bytes'));

Plan hash value: 532877948

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name         | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |              |     1 | 92867   (1)| 00:00:04 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                         |              |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL             | EMPLOYEE     |   100K|   114   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   VIEW                          |              |     1 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    COUNT                        |              |       |            |          |
|*  5 |     FILTER                      |              |       |            |          |
|*  6 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| DEPARTMENT   |     1 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0013596 |     1 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter( EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM  (SELECT "DEPT_ID" "DEPT_ID",ROWNUM 
              "ROWNUM/*ROWNUMADDEDFORPERFORMA" FROM "DEPARTMENT" "DEPARTMENT" WHERE :B1=1 AND 
              "DEPARTMENT"."DEPT_ID"=:B2 AND "DEPARTMENT"."NAME"='2') "from$_subquery$_002" 
              WHERE "DEPT_ID"=:B3))
   3 - filter("DEPT_ID"=:B1)
   5 - filter(:B1=1)
   6 - filter("DEPARTMENT"."NAME"='2')
   7 - access("DEPARTMENT"."DEPT_ID"=:B1)
```

**Or use `ROWNUM` to find the hints**

Even if you don't plan to use this `ROWNUM` trick in your final code it can still be helpful.  Run `explain plan for ...` with and without the `ROWNUM`.  Then use this statement to compare the full set of hints for each version:

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => '+alias +outline'));
```

The results will contain many complicated and undocumented hints.  Hopefully some of them will provide a clue about which hints are really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle 11g optimizer is quite clever (sometimes a bit too clever) when analyzing subqueries.  It may decide to internally transform a SELECT with a subquery inside a WHERE into a flat join.

That depends a lot of the optimizer and the query behind the view.  You will need to rewrite your query and see what works.

You can try this:

```
SELECT p.property_value
  FROM employee_contract_properties p
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM department d INNER JOIN employee e ON e.dept_id = d.id AND a.job = 'DBA'
    WHERE d.name = 'IT'
      AND e.id + 0 = p.empl_id
)
AND p.property_name = 'empl_cat_name';
```

The e.id + 0 is to hopefully fool the optimizer and think there isn't a reason to join the view with the two tables in the subquery.

You can also try this:

```
SELECT p.property_value
  FROM employee_contract_properties p,
       (SELECT e.id + 0
    FROM department d INNER JOIN employee e ON e.dept_id = d.id AND a.job = 'DBA'
    WHERE d.name = 'IT') inl
WHERE p.empl_id = inl.id
  AND p.property_name = 'empl_cat_name';
```

Again, the e.id + 0 is to hopefully fool the optimizer and prevent it from joining the view and the two tables.